# Issues with creating a web map using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm currently working on a web map using the Leaflet library but I'm running into several issues. I hope someone here can help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here are the issues I'm encountering:

1. Adding a title that indicates the selected city and a subtitle with my name.
2. Adding the plugin that allows displaying the location map.
3. Loading a point layer with Omnivore and changing the style of the points, either by another marker or by styled circles. In addition, displaying the attributes of the point layer loaded with Omnivore in a pop-up.
4. Adding the editing (draw) plugin, modifying the options so that only the tools to draw points, lines, and polygons appear (without circles or squares). I would also like to include the functionality to configure the style of the drawn polygons.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Zurich (Switzerland) - Mariano Salas Martinez</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
        <script src="path://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
        <script src="path://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-omnivore/v0.3.1/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
        <script src="path://unpkg.com/leaflet.locatecontrol@0.72.0/dist/L.Control.Locate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./data/train_stations.js"></script>

        <!-- Mini Map Plugin -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Plugins/Leaflet-MiniMap-master/src/Control.MiniMap.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Control.MiniMap.js"></script>
        <style>
            #map {
                width: 800px;
                height: 600px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapid" style="height: 910px; border: 1px solid #AAA;"></div>
        <script src="path://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="path://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leafletomnivore/v0.3.1/leaflet-omnivore.min.js"></script>
        <script src="path://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./data/train_stations.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Initialize the map centered on Zurich
            var map = L.map('mapid').setView([47.3769, 8.5417], 13);

            // Load a TileLayer
            var cartoVoyager = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager_nolabels/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
                subdomains: 'abcd',
                maxZoom: 19
            });

            // Load a WMS layer
            var zurichWMS = L.tileLayer.wms("path://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities", {
                layers: 'ch.swisstopo.swissimage',
                format: 'image/png',
                transparent: true,
                attribution: "Federal Office of Topography"
            }).addTo(map);

            // Create and load a GeoJSON layer
            // (Ensure that your GeoJSON data contains the three required attributes)
            var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(train_stations, {
                onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
                    var popupContent = '';
                    for (var prop in feature.properties) {
                        if (prop === 'image') {
                            popupContent += '<img src="' + feature.properties[prop] + '" style="width:100%;height:auto;"><br/>';
                        } else {
                            popupContent += prop + ': ' + feature.properties[prop] + '<br/>';
                        }
                    }
                    layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
                }
            });

            // Create an empty point layer for the boat stations
            var kmlLayer = new L.LayerGroup();

            // Load a point layer from the KML file using Leaflet.KML
            fetch('data/Boats.kml')
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.text();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
                var placemarks = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('Placemark');
                for (var i = 0; i < placemarks.length; i++) {
                    var coordinates = placemarks[i].getElementsByTagName('coordinates')[0].textContent;
                    var coords = coordinates.split(',');
                    var lat = parseFloat(coords[1]);
                    var lng = parseFloat(coords[0]);
                    var marker = L.marker([lat, lng]);
                    kmlLayer.addLayer(marker);
                }
            });

            // Define the layer object for the layer selector
            var baseLayers = {
                "Standard": cartoVoyager,
                "Satellite": zurichWMS
            };

            var overlays = {
                "Train Stations": geojsonLayer,
                "Boat Stations": k
```